# In which Star Trek TOS episode do the protagonists have to stay awake?

Tags: story-identification, star-trek, star-trek-tos, episode-identification

I am seeking to identify a Star Trek TOS (IIRC) episode.

In my unreliable recollection, two Starfleet protagonists out of Spock, Bones, and Kirk are stranded on a planet and have to stay awake until day-break, otherwise risking going to sleep permanently.

I dimly recall that the landscape was arid, and that some sort of gas was released during the night-time; and that if you fell asleep, then the sleep was permanent. The two protagonists kept each other awake by recounting stories to each other.

Any assistance is most gratefully appreciated. Thank you very much.

Comment: So not http://memory-alpha.wikia.com/wiki/Waking_Moments_(episode)?

Comment: One of the characters was very concerned about being attacked in his dreams in [Is There In Truth No Beauty?](http://www.chakoteya.net/StarTrek/62.htm)

Comment: There were a few episodes that dealt with sleep or lack of i.e. night terrors, sleep deprivation, etc., but nothing in TOS that fits your description.  Try to remember a few more details.

Comment: That would probably be Bones and Kirk; Spock is likely to be able to go on for weeks on end without sleeping.

Comment: Thank you very much for everyone's assistance.

Alas, I can only present a fragment of a shard of a little pinkie bone, in terms of context, and I apologise for the uninformative ambiguity.

I dimly recall that the landscape was arid, and that some sort of gas was released during the night-time, and that if you fell asleep, then the sleep was permanent. The two protagonists kept each other awake by recounting stories to each other.

I am pretty sure, it was ST (at least!).

Best regards,

Comment: @BrianWestlake: I am pretty certain there is no Star Trek episode that plays out exactly like this. Do you happen to remember any of the stories they recount to each other? Stated like this, it almost sounds as if the story you are remembering is a framing device for several short stories.

Comment: @BrianWestlake: Based on your unreliable recollection, the closest I can come up with is an episode from Enterprise, not TOS, where Tucker and Reed keep each other awake by relating stories from their past and recording messages to their families while awaiting rescue while their air is running out. [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shuttlepod_One) Maybe this will jog your memory and you can remember some more details.

Comment: Thank you everybody, alas, no further details come to mind. A friend recalls seeing such an episode, but cannot recall any fingerable context other that it was related to Kirk's quest for a beautiful woman - however that does not disambiguate much, in the scheme of things!

Comment: No such TOS episode. Perhaps an Enterprise episode.

Comment: Also, sounds like a Stargate SG1 episode ["Morpheus"](http://www.gateworld.net/sg1/s10/1002.shtml)

Comment: @AnthonyX: Yes, thank you very much, I've reviewed SG1 "Morpheus", and it is a close analogue of what my unreliable memory recalls, however the Quest continues! - Albeit, perhaps, outside the frame of ST.